# Perl call import from base class

Tags: perl, oop, import, radix

I have a base class called `A`:

```
package A;
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.12;

sub import {
    my $caller = caller;
say 'import called from ' . $caller;
    if (not $caller->can('has')) {
        no strict 'refs';
say "--> import has to $caller";
        *{"${caller}::has"} = sub { _attr($caller, @_) };
    }
}

sub _attr {
    my ($class, $name, $default) = @_;
    no strict 'refs';
    *{"${class}::$name"} = sub {
        my ($self, $value) = @_;
        $self->{$name} = $value if $value;
        return $self->{$name} // $default;
    };
}

1;
```

And have a child class `B`:

```
package B;
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib './';
use base 'A';
use v5.12;

#use C;
A->import();

has 'ans' => 42;
say ans();

1;
```

If I'm trying to run this code, I've got an syntax error
but if I make these changes `has 'ans' => 42'` to `has('ans' => 42);` then all works great.

Or if I've create class `C`:

```
package C;
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib '.';
use base 'A';

1;
```

then I do not need to modify this code `has 'ans'...` to `has(...` because all is works.

So, I've can't understand why this happens.
How I can import subroutine `has` in a child modules?

Comment: there is a core module B.pm; beware of conflict there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import `has` from `A` into any other module you simply need to put `use A` into that module.

Replace this line:

```
A->import();
```

with:

```
use A;
```

and it will do what you want.

Manually calling `->import` doesn't do what you want because it happens at run time, and the import needs to happen at compile time in order for `perl` to know that `has` is a subroutine name before it parses the line that uses it. `use` is a compile-time command, so has effect before the `has` line gets parsed.

Comment: Actually `->import` is calling and I can use `has` but only with brackets. Without brackets I get a syntax error.

Comment: Yes. `->import` is being called, but only at run time, not compile time. So without the parens, when `perl` is compiling the line with `has` in, it doesn't know that `has` is a sub name. If you want `perl` to be able to compile a bare `has` as a sub name, you have to let it know at compile time. Which is what `use` does.